# VBA get rid of full row if one specific column repeats a word in next row

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a vba code to get rid of a row if any word is immediately repeated in same column (column E) but in other row. If that happens, the row to be deleted is the one more on top. Follow an example below. In this case, the row to be dropped are: E6, E10 and E15.

Name of the sheet is test. Columns and F and G are not relevant.

Thanks a lot!

[image]

Edit to add code from comments:

```
Sub delete_duplicates_column_E()
    With Sheets("test").Range("A:E")
        .Value = .Value
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=5, Header:=xlYes
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show what code you've written so far?

Comment: yes. but is not doing excactly what i want, coz removes all duplicates. See below:

"Sub delete_duplicates_column_E()

    With Sheets("test").Range("A:E")
        .Value = .Value 
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=5, Header:=xlYes 
    End With


End Sub"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just whipped this up, try it:

`Sub removeDuplicates()
    Range("E2").Select
    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
        If ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(1).Value Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete (xlShiftUp)
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
    Loop
End Sub`

Comment: seems be working! thanks!
Added to your code just 
Set ws = Sheets("test")
ws.Select

ws.Range("E2").Select

Comment: Not a problem, just remember `.select` can be quite volatile and should be avoided whenever it can.

Answer (score 0):

When deleting rows it is better to loop back wards:

```
Sub delete_duplicates_column_E()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("test")
    With ws
        lastrow = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
            If .Cells(i, 5) = .Cells(i + 1, 5) Then
                .Rows(i).Delete
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```